# Restricting access to particular directory in java

Tags: java, python, symlink, chroot

EDIT :
Is there any way to change root directory of a particular thread in Java? So all operations(read, write, create etc..) are restricted to that particular folder. Python provides this functionality via [os.chroot](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chroot) API. What's the equivalent way to achieve this in Java? I am going to execute my code only in Linux platform itself. No platform independence is required.

ORIGINAL :
My all read/write operations should be restricted to a directory called /home/test1. Even if that directory contains symbolic links to an external location(/home/test2 or /home/mydir), those links should be broken for my java program so an exception should be thrown.

Is there any way to do this in java?

Comment: Does `File.getCanonicalPath` help you here?

Comment: File.getCanonicalPath doesn't return the target of the link if link is broken(actually no physical resource exists). It is still exploitable while creating any resource(file/folder).                 readSymbolicLink only returns the immediate target so this also fails if there is chain of symbolic links.                                      There are third parties which also perform IO in that folder and they didn't guarantee about symbolic links.

Comment: @JonSkeet Any suggestions with above requirements?

Comment: No, but I'm finding it hard to parse your objections. It would make things simpler if you'd give examples in your question, and how `readSymbolicLink` and `getCanonicalPath` wouldn't help you.